# jQuery UI resizable - limit to parent width, and leave height to auto

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I do need to use jQuery UI resizable with parent limits only to width, and leave height to auto.

As i see it's not possible through regular way, and we have to do something else through jQuery. I've already tried through event `resize`, to get `current height of resizing element` and compare is it close to a `parent` height, if it's `close`, i would increase `height` of `parent` and i'm okay.

But the problem is, it happens (height increased), but jquery ui `keeps somewhere` the `height` of a parent when it started with resize of a element, and it has no effect untill you stop resizing, and try again *(it will repeat step, increase once, and won't recognize increased area of parent, untill it's stopped, and started again).*

**I've created snippets why do i need to use `containment` instead of only `maxWidth`.**

I hope someone has some method to do this, i wouldn't mind if someone has idea to do it through `maxWidth` but to has same effect as in snippet with `containment`.

With `containment` it allows me to have two blocks at one row, and when i resize last one to the end, it won't pass to second row, but with `maxWidth` it does pass to next row (that's why `maxWidth` can't help me).

The snippet:

```css
#body {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
}

.blocks, .blocks2 {
   border: 1px dashed gray;
   display: inline-block;
   min-height: 32px;
   width: 150px;
}

#body2 {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

With containment:<br>
<div id="body">
  <div class="blocks">test my block</div>
  <div class="blocks">resize this to end</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<div style="color: #003c98;">As you can see, second with max-width, goes to next row, but i want to keep it to end if theres two or more of divs at inline position</div>

<div id="body2">
  <div class="blocks2">test my block</div>
  <div class="blocks2">resize this to end</div>
</div>

<script>
var body_height = 50;
$(function(){
  
  $('.blocks').resizable({
   maxWidth: 500,
      minHeight: 32,
   minWidth: 15,
   containment: "#body",
      resize: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.size.height >= body_height-50) { 
            body_height += 100;
            $('#body').css('height', body_height);
        }
      }
  });
  
  $('.blocks2').resizable({
   maxWidth: 500,
      minHeight: 32,
   minWidth: 15
  });
  
});
</script>
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code snippet allows resizing the selected block up to the total width of the container. It sets `maxWidth` at the start of the resizing operation, allowing the block to take the remaining space on its right.

```js
$(function () {
    var containerWidth = $("#body").width();
    var getCurrentBlockRight = function ($currentBlock) {
        var $parent = $currentBlock.parent();
        return $currentBlock.offset().left + $currentBlock.outerWidth() - $parent.offset().left - parseInt($parent.css("padding-left"), 10);
    };
    $('.block').resizable({
        maxWidth: containerWidth,
        minHeight: 32,
        minWidth: 15,
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var $currentBlock = $(this);
            var width = $(this).width();
            $currentBlock.resizable("option", "maxWidth", width + containerWidth - getCurrentBlockRight($currentBlock));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.block
{
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 32px;
    width: 130px;
}

#body
{
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="body">
    <div class="block">test1</div>
    <div class="block">test2</div>
    <div class="block">test3</div>
    <div class="block">test4</div>
    <div class="block">test5</div>
    <div class="block">test6</div>
    <div class="block">test7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: woah, great :) Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically adjusting the `maxWidth` can get what you want.

```css
#body {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blocks {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 32px;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="body">
  <div class="blocks">test my block</div>
  <div class="blocks">resize this to end</div>
</div>

<script>
  //calculate flexibly
  var gap = 6;
  $(function() {

    $('#body .blocks:eq(0)').resizable({
      maxWidth: getMaxWidth($('#body .blocks:eq(0)')),
      minHeight: 32,
      minWidth: 15,
      stop: updateMaxWidth
    });
    $('#body .blocks:eq(1)').resizable({
      maxWidth: getMaxWidth($('#body .blocks:eq(1)')),
      minHeight: 32,
      minWidth: 15,
      stop: updateMaxWidth
    });

    function getMaxWidth(e) {
      return $('#body').width() - e.siblings().outerWidth() - gap;
    }

    function updateMaxWidth(e, ui) {
      ui.element.siblings().resizable('option', 'maxWidth', getMaxWidth(ui.element.siblings()));
    }

  });
</script>
```

or see this [demo](http://codepen.io/arlendp/pen/yVojyb) in codepen.

Comment: This is great, but i didn't explain again well, i were missed one thing, there's possibility to be much more blocks, and every new row, should behave similar, i believe this is working at your example, but i need it also to all blocks at one row (`except last one`) can be resized to end, pulling all others after the one beign resized to new line/row.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the container's width in the `maxWidth` property:

```
$('.blocks').resizable({
    maxWidth: $('#body').width(),
    minHeight: 32,
    minWidth: 15,
});
```

```css
#body {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.blocks {
   width: 500px;
   border: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  
  <div class="blocks">
     test my block
  </div>
  
</div>


<script>
var body_height = 50;
$(function(){
  
  $('.blocks').resizable({
   maxWidth: $('#body').width(),
      minHeight: 32,
   minWidth: 15,
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but i could solve it like that, i said above, but with `containment` i get something else, i will try to re-organize question in next 10 minutes... Best regards.